# How to retrive object from rethinkdb asynchornus nodejs

Tags: node.js, rethinkdb

I try to get collection of questions using rethinkdb, but I've problem with returning collection. How Can I code getQuestion function to retrun collection and use it like this:

```
var questions = getQuetions(); 

function getQuestions() {

   var question;
   r.table("questions")
      .run()
      .then(function (response) {
          questions = response;                             
      })
      .error(function (err) {
          console.log('error occurred ', err);
      });
   return questions;
}
```

I'm just starting with node, so can you help me with asynchornus approach on this case?

Answer (score 0):

Since querying db is asynchronous you can't use *return* statement. It would return before any results are return from the db. You can use callback as shown bellow.

```
getQuestions(function(err, result){
    console.log(err, result);
}); 

function getQuestions(callback) {

   r.table("questions")
      .run()
      .then(function (response) {
          callback(null, response);                             
      })
      .error(function (err) {
          callback(err); 
      });
}
```